# How to properly use label when putting design with only placeholder online

Tags: css, html, accessibility

I'm working in a web agency, and I recently had a small question and could not find the answer. A designer gave me a PSD file with a form without labels in the form, only placeholders. Last time I had this, I went straight forward with the HTML5 placeholder attributes (with javascript fallback for old browser). However, then I read a lot and realized most people are saying that you must have label in form for accessibility. Therefore, I was wondering what was the best way to have both : the accessibility of the label and the placeholder without having the label into the ''minimal'' design that the designer gave me. Should I put them in visibility hidden just for the screen readers with an absolute positioning or something like this ? Here's a picture example of what I have to do (just so you understand clearly the context). It's in french, but I'm sure you still can understand what I mean!

You can see an example of the [image]

Comment: This might be helpful: http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/

Comment: In french, AcceDe Web has written 4 documents to different profiles. The first one is for webdesigners, send your colleagues or clients this link ;) [notice d’accessibilité pour la conception graphique](http://accede-web.com/fr/notices/) (or you can use it in a checklist for internal use, license is CC-BY)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on steveax's comment and link, there are a couple ways it could be implemented. Since there is no interactivity in the label by itself, you could do something like

```
label {
  height: 1px;
  text-indent: -1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Another option would be the more comprehensive hiding technique that WebAIM mentions, namely

```
.hidden {
  position:absolute;
  left:-10000px;
  top:auto;
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

[Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/igupun/1/edit) of each on a text input.

If it is possible though, I would recommend trying to get the design tweaked to include the labels visually as well. A [number](http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/08/05/dont_use_placeholder_text_as_labels/) of [sources](http://laurakalbag.com/labels-in-input-fields-arent-such-a-good-idea/) will cite the [negative](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/form-placeholder-text/) effects of using placeholder text [exclusively](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28511/does-the-content-of-the-html5-placeholder-attribute-affect-usability).

Answer (score -3):

You can simply use `display: none;`

Comment: If I use display none, it have no accessibility property since even most of eyes reader wont see it and users wont see it neither, so it'd be just useless code to put

Comment: Bah. 
The users will see either the placeholder or the javascript follback you said you coded.

Comment: Yeah but for accessibility matters, for people who are blind or are having eye problem, label are helping them alot using forms

Comment: Could you post your reference on how labels helping blind people?

Comment: Sure ! Here's a great article about the label tag, and why you should always use it ! 

http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/aa052206.htm

Comment: [WCAG 2.0 using label elements to associate text labels with form controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20120103/H44)

Comment: I see. How about always using the label as the placeholder text? It will be placed on top of the input element and be hidden when the user focuses on the input. You probably already implemented this behavior as a fallback for older browsers that don't support the placeholder attribute, so you could just stick to it.

Comment: If by `hidden` you mean `.visually-hidden` (with negative text-indent or clip()) then maybe; if you mean `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` then NOPE for the same reasons. You're removing the label from screen readers: maybe they won't update and keep the original text from label maybe they will and oh! there isn't a label anymore. At least this isn't robust and future-proof but it may already fail in some or all screen readers right now.